# SQL-Server Create database on remote server without linked server

Tags: sql-server, external

Using: SQL-Server 2016+

I am trying to Create a database on a remote server from my local server.

I have a connection string to the SA user, and can use openrowset to view data, but not to execute commands.

I do not have clients permission to use Linked Servers because of the security risk, and they will not be convinced otherwise.

Any idea what best practice for achieving this would be?

Comment: Re "I have a connection string to the SA user" - couldn't you just connect with SSMS then?

Comment: I'm with @Arvo here. Don't overthink this. Just open a connection on the other server and create your table.

Comment: I think "I have a connection string to the SA user" = he is sysadmin on server A, but has no direct access to server B, and he wants to execute smth from local server where he is sysadmin but linked server was set up by someone else and he does not know server B's logins/passwords, so the only way to him to use server B is to use linked server under some limited login to which he is mapped to

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the replies. The situation here is I have been asked to create a deployment centre that creates a database on a clients machine (which they need to provide sa or similar access to) and then populates a table of updates that will be run locally.  This is not the way I'd usually work, but it's where I've ended up.  This needs to be an "unattended" setup process triggered by the user, rather than me sitting on their SQL server running scripts (which is what I've always done in the past)

Answer (score 0):

You could use SSIS to connect to the other server and Execute SQL task to issue commands.

You could also write a .net app or maybe a CLR proc.